# How to set a timeout for a process under Windows 7?

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7, timeout

I would like to start a program with a Windows batch file. But the program should stop after a certain timeout value. For example: Run the program 60 seconds and stop it after 60 seconds.

Under Linux, there is this nice `timeout` command to do what I want. Windows has also a `timeout` command, but it's just to pause a command, to delay it's execution. Is there something else under Windows to do so?

Setup: Windows 7, 64 Bit, Professional

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
start yourprogram.exe
timeout /t 60
taskkill /im yourprogram.exe /f
```

Comment: Thank you, works great. Is it also possible to stop another batch script with taskkill ? I could not figure out how to do this.

Comment: No problem, that's a bit more tricky. As they are all under the same `cmd.exe` process you would need another way of separating them. You could give it a specific title like `start "mybatch" batchfile.bat` then you could use taskkill like `taskkill /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq mybatch" /f`

Comment: @John  You need to title you bat scripts first using the title commands.

Comment: Just to add a bit.. to use just single line, you may try: `start "" app.exe & timeout /t 60 & taskkill /im app.exe /f`

Comment: If program ends earlier than after 60 seconds, it need still wait. Is it possible to wait until program finishes but no longer than 60 seconds?

Comment: Can be made a bit more generic with start "" "%1" and taskkill /im "%~nx1" /f

Comment: @BaliC how can I put this script in a single line for CMD?

Comment: this also doesn't work when there are multiple instances of `yourprogram.exe` like other solutions

Answer (score 14):

Bali C gave a concise and to the point answer.
I needed something a little more featureful and reusable.
Based on Bali C's Example. I came up with this.
If anyone should need the same as me.

your.bat

```
REM...

CALL STARTwaitKILL..bat /relative/path/your_program.exe

REM...
```

STARTwaitKILL.BAT

```
@ECHO OFF 
IF[%1]==[] GOTO EOF
IF NOT EXIST %1 GOTO EOF

REM SET PRIORITY=/NORMAL
REM ADJUST PRIORITY, BELOWNORMAL LETS BATCH FILE RUN MORE SMOOTHLY
REM WITH A PROGRAM THAT CONSUMES MORE CPU. SEE ABOUT MAXWAIT BELLOW
SET PRIORITY=/BELOWNORMAL
REM SET PRIORITY=/LOW
REM 0 NORMAL WINDOW :: 1 NO WINDOW :: 2 MINIMIZED WINDOW
SET /A HIDDEN=1
REM MAXWAIT HERE IS MORE LIKE MINIMUM WAIT IN WINDOWS.
SET MAXWAIT=10
SET WAITCOUNT=0

SET ARGS=/I %PRIORITY%
IF %HIDDEN% EQU 1 SET ARGS=%ARGS% /B
IF %HIDDEN% EQU 2 SET ARGS=%ARGS% /MIN

START %ARGS% %1

:WAIT
IF %WAITCOUNT% GEQ %MAXWAIT% GOTO KILL_IT

TIMEOUT /T 1 > NUL
SET /A WAITCOUNT+=1
FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN ('TASKLIST ^| FIND /C "%~nx1"') DO IF %%a EQU 0 GOTO RUN_DONE
GOTO WAIT

:KILL_IT
TASKKILL /IM %~nx1 /F > NUL
:RUN_DONE
```

Could be fleshed out ore to take more arguments for priority and such, but I don't have the need for it. Shouldn't be hard to add.

Comment: This version has the benefit of not waiting for the full timeout period when the process ends sooner. Just ignore the PRIORITY and HIDDEN stuff if you don't care about them.

Answer (score 5):

The `start`+`timeout`+`taskkill` waits **exactly** the given time. Since I needed to **stop waiting if the process exits earlier**, I created my own solution in C++.

The `tuxliketimeout` program  mimics the [GNU timeout](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html). Feel free to download&compile from

https://github.com/cernoch/tuxliketimeout

Comment: Not quite the same though. E.g. it's missing the soft / hardkill differentiation. GNU timeout e.g. allows to trigger a soft fault first, in which e.g. Google breakpad can still perform a core dump, before later on hard killing the process.

Answer (score 4):

Don't exist any command in Windows to delay an app or to set a timeout for an app

Timeout in Windows is for Delay the execution process of CMD/Batfile, nothing more utility.

You can use external tools for that, I don't remember the name of any now, so many underground software, sorry, but I remember that in the autoit official forum exists a similar commandline tool to launch an app setting the timeout,
and maybe in the tool NIRCMD, or ps2exec, check their help files, or someone inside the WAIK Kits.

This is the only you can do:

```
@Echo OFF

:: First launch the app in background mode, because some applications stops the execution of CMD.
Start /B ".\Dir\Your app.exe"

:: Then stay in background for a certain time
Timeout /T "Seconds"

:: Continue your code...
Pause&Exit
```

Answer (score 4):

In windows 10 the easiest way is with [scriptrunner](https://ss64.com/nt/scriptrunner.html):

Demonstrate the timeout by running a pause command (this will kill the called process):

```
ScriptRunner.exe -appvscript cmd "/c" "pause" -appvscriptrunnerparameters -wait -timeout=20
```

Comment: That looks like a feature designed to handle the specific problem.  I'm impressed with the work that went into the other answers, and I think yours is the best one if scriptrunner is built into your OS.  Almost 2 years and no love!  Have a vote.  It is at least a great answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Wait-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/wait-job) for this. It'll return immediately if the command doesn't time out so you don't have to wait the full time. It also doesn't fail when there are multiple instances of the same app running like  [Bali C's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13515320/995714). Just put the below function into the profile by running `notepad $PROFILE` in PowerShell and paste this snippet

```powershell
Function Invoke-WithTimeOut {
    Param (
        [int]$timeout,
        [scriptblock]$script
    )

    $job = Start-Job $script
    $done = $job | Wait-Job -TimeOut $timeout
    if (-not $done) { Stop-Job $job }
}
```

Then you can use it in any PowerShell sessions. For example to run `yourprogram.exe` with 40s timeout

```powershell
Invoke-WithTimeOut 40 { yourprogram.exe }
```

You can call that from a batch file like this

```powershell
powershell -C "Invoke-WithTimeOut 40 { yourprogram.exe }"
```

But it's better to use PowerShell these days

Of course you can also run it directly if you just want to do that once

```powershell
$job = sajb { yourprogram.exe }
if (-not ($job | wjb -T 60)) { spjb $job }
```

You can change `Start-Job`/`Wait-Job` to [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process)/[`Wait-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/wait-process) which will produce the same result as the [`ScriptRunner.exe` solution by npocmaka](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64787661/995714)