# Run two programmes on command prompt and kill one of them after a delay

Tags: batch-file

I have two programmes, both are long running codes. I want to run them on command prompt parallelly and after some delay I want to kill one programm. how it could be done with batch file? I have tried the solution given [How to set a timeout for a process under Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515254/how-to-set-a-timeout-for-a-process-under-windows-7) 
the solution is killing the command prompt itself.
I have tried:

**moniter_batch.bat**

```
start note.py
start test.py
timeout /t 10
taskkill /im python.exe /f
```

**note.py**

```
import time
while True:
    print "I am ok\n"
    time.sleep(1)
```

**test.py**

```
import time
while True:
    print "I am ok\n"
    time.sleep(1)
```

I want to kill **note.py** only and **test.py** must continue but my batch file is killing both the programmes

Comment: If you start by providing your code, it gives people the opportunity to help you with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try getting a list of processes with:

```
TASKLIST /V /FO "CSV" | FINDSTR note
```

**Sample Output**

```
C:\>tasklist /v /fo "CSV" | FINDSTR note
"cmd.exe","828","Console","0","2,492 K","Running","WINXP\Person","0:00:00","C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe - note"
```

and then using the PID (in the second field) with `TASKKILL`:

```
TASKKILL /PID 828
```