# Start external program and check if it has crashed

Tags: r, windows, multithreading

I have the following situation: In my R script I start a third-party program with `system2`. The program is called lots of times, and unfortunately it is not very stable and crashes sometimes. If this happens, control is not returned to R until I kill the program via Task Manager manually.

What I would like to do: If the program has not returned control after 10 minutes, kill it automatically.

I could of course wrap the program in C++, Java or similar, implement this functionality in the wrapper, and call the wrapper from R. Quite possibly I could also utilize `Rcpp`.

However, I wonder if there is any way to achive this in R directly?

Btw: I am on Windows 7.

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a unix-like system, you can add the unix command `timeout` to your system call. Example:

```
# system command that times out
> exitcode = system('timeout 1 sleep 20')
> exitcode
[1] 124

# system command that does not time out
> exitcode = system('timeout 2 sleep 1')
> exitcode
[1] 0
```

`system` returns the exit status of the process so you can check whether it is 0 (OK) or 124 (timed out).

Comment: Thanks, that is a good idea! Unfortuantely im on Windows. I will also add that information to my question.

Comment: Here a question about timeout command on windows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515254/how-to-set-a-timeout-for-a-process-under-windows-7 and a Microsoft man page: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754891(v=ws.11).aspx