# How to kill a C++ program after say t seconds in Windows Command Prompt?

Tags: c++, c++17, sublimetext3, sublimetext

```
#include"bits/stdc++.h"
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
// #ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
//     freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
//     freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
// #endif
    int x = 1;
    while (x < 100) {
        cout << x;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Which flag or script should I add in Command Prompt while running this program such that it kills the process after some time(say 1 second) and doesn't hang my computer ?Actually I want to make a `sublime-build` that kills the process say after t seconds but the `timeout` in windows is used for waiting unlike the `timeout` in `linux`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set a timeout for a process under Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515254/how-to-set-a-timeout-for-a-process-under-windows-7)

Comment: No I tried this but the program doesnt't stops

Comment: Also Should I ask another question because this one got associated with that question ?I am new to Stack-Overflow .

Comment: In an async thread use Sleep(milliseconds); to pause a program, and exit(3); to terminate it

Comment: @LightningGaming should I write myprogram.exe exit(3) ? Also what is 3 here ?

Comment: If you're this new to C++, you shouldnt be learning bad practices from competitive programming(`#include "bits/stdc++.h"` and `using namespace std;` are both bad) and should first follow an actual C++ tutorial.

Comment: See [Why is `using namespace std` considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) and [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) for details...